# UPS Street Validation integration on Bigcommerce store

Tags: bigcommerce, ups

We're looking for a BC Partner to help integrate UPS Street Validation on on our Bigcommerce store, can this be done on Bigcommerce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is feasible to accomplish this, but it would be through javascript since the street info wouldn't be accessible through the BC API until the order was placed.

Alternatively, you can checkout an integration like [Addrexx](https://addrexx.com/).